# How to optionally import a Spring managed component?

Tags: java, spring

I have created a custom API jar library where I'd like to provide some commonly used services.

But I'd like to use and autowire some of these services optionally in my implementation projects. They should not get autowired automatically.

How could I tell `Spring` explicit to include the following `StatsLogger`?

API jar:

```
package my.spring.config

//@Component
public class MyStatsLogger {

    @Autowired
    private MyService someOtherServiceForLogging;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60000) 
    public void log() {
        //logging
    }   
}
```

IMPL project:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {

}
```

Comment: Does `MyStatsLogger` have any autowired dependencies? What does it's constructor look like?

Comment: Is `MyService` annotated with `@Component` or `@Service`?

Comment: I was just asking in case you wanted to configure it just like `MyStatsLogger`, without the stereotype annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the service to your context:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public MyStatsLogger myStatsLogger() {
        return new MyStatsLogger();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `MyStatsLogger` has a default constructor, all you need to is the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {


    @Bean
    public MyStatsLogger myStatsLogger() {
       return new MyStatsLogger();
    }
}
```

The `MyService` dependency in `MyStatsLogger` will automatically be wired by Spring if of course there is a bean of type `MyService` declared.